# convert a dynamodb scan to query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've written a API gateway to scan a dynamodb table and get values based on the condition and my code is as below.

```
var params = {
        TableName: 'CarsData',
        FilterExpression: '#market_category = :market_category and #vehicle_size = :vehicle_size and #transmission_type = :transmission_type and #price_range = :price_range and #doors = :doors',
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#market_category": "market_category",
            "#vehicle_size": "vehicle_size",
            "#transmission_type": "transmission_type",
            "#price_range": "price_range",
            "#doors": "doors"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":market_category": body.market_category,
            ":vehicle_size": body.vehicle_size,
            ":transmission_type": body.transmission_type,
            ":price_range": body.price_range,
            ":doors": body.doors
        }
    }
    dynamodb.scan(params).promise().then(function (data) {
        var uw = data.Items;
        console.log(data + "\n" + JSON.stringify(data) + "\n" + JSON.stringify(data.Items));
        var res = {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": {},
            "body": JSON.stringify(uw)
        };
        ctx.succeed(res);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        var res = {
            "statusCode": 404,
            "headers": {},
            "body": JSON.stringify({ "status": "error" })
        };
        ctx.succeed(res);
    });
```

when I run this code, I get the result as expected. But when I was going through some online forums, I came to know that scanning is expensive compared to querying. But I'm unable to know on how can I change my query from scan to query. Here my primary key is ID. please let me know on how can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Scan operation is more expensive comparing to query operation, in terms of performance as well as costing. Dynamodb calculates cost based on the number of read capacity units consumed for processing not on number of records returned.

Query operation finds value based on **primary key (Hash) or composite primary key (Hash key and Sort Key).**

> Your schema should be redesigned with composite primary key(Hash key and Sort Key).

Its not neccessary to have column **Id** as primary Key like old school RDBMS. If you are not using Id effectively remove that column from your schema and redefine it with some other attributes. For an example am using Market Category (market_category ) as Hash Key & Price Range (price_range) as Range Key.

```
var params = {
            "TableName": 'CarsData',
            "ConsistentRead": true,

            //Composite Primary Key in Key Condition Expression
            "KeyConditionExpression": "#market_category = :market_category AND #price_range = :price_range",

            //Remaining column in filter expression 
            "FilterExpression": '#vehicle_size = :vehicle_size and #transmission_type = :transmission_type and #doors = :doors',
            "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
                "#market_category": "market_category",
                "#vehicle_size": "vehicle_size",
                "#transmission_type": "transmission_type",
                "#price_range": "price_range",
                "#doors": "doors"
            },
            "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
                ":market_category": body.market_category,
                ":vehicle_size": body.vehicle_size,
                ":transmission_type": body.transmission_type,
                ":price_range": body.price_range,
                ":doors": body.doors
            }
        }

    dynamodb.query(params).promise()
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Hope this example will give you insights about using composite primary key, 
Based on your usage choose the widely used columns for Hash & Range key.